# CNN classification

Tags: python, classification, conv-neural-network

I have developed a CNN classification model to classify cats and dogs. When I test the model using any any image which is neither a cat nor a dog, (for example picture of a sky or chair), it predicts them as dog with 0.99 probability. Any idea why this is happening?. Does this mean the model is overfiting?

Model definition is as below,

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Dense,MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Activation,Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.backend import tf as ktf
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

def mean_subtract(img):
    #img = T.set_subtensor(img[:,0,:,:],img[:,0,:,:] - 123.68)
    #img = T.set_subtensor(img[:,1,:,:],img[:,1,:,:] - 116.779)
    #img = T.set_subtensor(img[:,2,:,:],img[:,2,:,:] - 103.939)
    return img / 255.0


def cats_dogs_model():
    input_shape = (3, 256, 256)

    x_input = Input(input_shape)
    x = Lambda(mean_subtract, name='mean_subtraction')(x_input)

    # Conv Layer 1
    x = Convolution2D(96, 7, 7, subsample=(4,4), activation='relu',
                      name='conv_1', init='he_normal')(x_input) 
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2,2))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = ZeroPadding2D((2,2))(x)

    # Conv Layer 2
    x = Convolution2D(256, 5, 5, activation='relu', name='conv_2', init='he_normal')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = ZeroPadding2D((2, 2))(x)

    # Conv Layer 3
    x = Convolution2D(384, 3, 3, activation='relu',
                      name='conv_3', init='he_normal')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)    
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    predictions = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)
    return Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=predictions)
```

Comment: can you provide some code of your model for better understanding?

Comment: I have added model definition to the question

Comment: Ceci n'est pas un chat 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a softmax activation on an output layer with 2 units, which makes your model a binary classifier. It's hard to give you a correct solution with no prior knowledge of your dataset, but it boils down to two probable cases:

- Your classification labels are mutually exclusive (either a dog or a cat, not both). In this case you should add a third class, provided your supervised dataset can be transformed accordingly.
- The labels are not mutually exclusive (both classes can be absent or present at once). In this case you should replace softmax with sigmoid and make sure your dataset is formatted the right way (for multi-label classification). This is equivalent to solving two independent binary classification problems at once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: My training dataset donot have representation for the "not both" class but how does the model predict the unknown class as "dog" all the time?

Comment: @AKSHAYAAVAIDYANATHAN your model, as it stands, doesn't have much choice. Since you only have two units and the softmax, the units are constrained to sum up to 1, which effectively forces your model to only really pay attention to one class (cats in your case). This preference might have something to do with the composition of training and testing samples, though it's notoriously hard to tell what's really happening in a deep network.

Comment: @AKSHAYAAVAIDYANATHAN _'My training dataset donot have representation for the "not both"'_ – then you should opt for the second solution (i.e. an output layer with two units and sigmoid activation).